# Android Map Marker on Longpress is Plotted Below the Area That is Actually LongPressed (on API 15)

Tags: android, android-mapview

I have been racking my brains for days now on this and have Googled and SO'ed but can't seem to find anyone else reporting such problem(could have missed it).

I have a customized Mapview Class that listens for longpress among others and am using it to plot markers on my map.  It plots okay on API-8.  But on API-15 the marker is offsetted by about 2cm below where the user finger is doing the longpress.  This is observed for both actual device (samsung s2) and eclipse emulator.  Also the finger area long-pressed versus the marker area plotted(offset by about 2cm) is observed on all zoom levels.

Here is my customized Mapview Class (yanked it from somewhere):

```
public class MyCustomMapView extends MapView {
public interface OnLongpressListener {
    public void onLongpress(MapView view, GeoPoint longpressLocation);
}

static final int LONGPRESS_THRESHOLD = 500;
private GeoPoint lastMapCenter;

private Timer longpressTimer = new Timer();
private MyCustomMapView.OnLongpressListener longpressListener;


public MyCustomMapView(Context context, String apiKey) {
    super(context, apiKey);
}

public MyCustomMapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public MyCustomMapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public void setOnLongpressListener(MyCustomMapView.OnLongpressListener listener) {
    longpressListener = listener;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    handleLongpress(event);

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

private void handleLongpress(final MotionEvent event) {

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        // Finger has touched screen.
        longpressTimer = new Timer();
        longpressTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                GeoPoint longpressLocation = getProjection().fromPixels((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());

                /*
                 * Fire the listener. We pass the map location
                 * of the longpress as well, in case it is needed
                 * by the caller.
                 */
                longpressListener.onLongpress(MyCustomMapView.this, longpressLocation);
            }

        }, LONGPRESS_THRESHOLD);

        lastMapCenter = getMapCenter();
    }

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

        if (!getMapCenter().equals(lastMapCenter)) {
            // User is panning the map, this is no longpress
            longpressTimer.cancel();
        }

        lastMapCenter = getMapCenter();
    }

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        // User has removed finger from map.
        longpressTimer.cancel();
    }

        if (event.getPointerCount() > 1) {
                    // This is a multitouch event, probably zooming.
            longpressTimer.cancel();
        }
}
```

And this is how I call the Class above:

```
custom_marker = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker3);
custom_marker.setBounds(-custom_marker.getIntrinsicWidth(), -custom_marker.getIntrinsicHeight(), 0, 0);
customSitesOverlay = new CustomSitesOverlay(custom_marker);
mapView.getOverlays().add(customSitesOverlay);
customSitesOverlay.addOverlay(new OverlayItem(longpressLocation, "User Marker", id));
```

Comment: I too facing the same issue. @Marka, have you found any solution then please share....Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry @MukeshY we abandoned this approached altogether and opted for a fixed pin on the map via code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a setBounds problem. You are setting the marker bounds to center in the bottom-right corner of drawable. Is that the intented behaviour?

You can set the marker to center in the bottom-center (which is the most usual type or markers) setting the bounds to:

```
custom_marker.setBounds(-custom_marker.getIntrinsicWidth()/2, -custom_marker.getIntrinsicHeight(), custom_marker.getIntrinsicWidth()/2, 0);
```

good luck.

Comment: Thanks @Luis but using your solution still results to the same behavior.  I have also tried varying these parameters as well in my quest for answers(forgot to mention that on the post sorry).  Moreover, am getting the intended behavior on the original setting using API 8.  Its just on API 15 that this behavior is currently observed(have not tried it on other versions).

Comment: You shouldn't get the same behaviour as you would be setting two different bounds for the drawable. If you are geting the same behaviour the you definitely have a bounds problem. I remember someone reporting about a similar problem, that after call an activity the bounds from the drawable were lost, but by the time there wasn't any solution accepted.

Comment: Right @luis ! It was being overridden with settings on the CustomSitesOverlay Class.  But have tried removing it and have a barebones plotting of markers on the actual long press activity and am still returning correct placement of markers on area pressed for API Level 8 (and an HTC device) and a about 2cm offset(marker is plotted 2cm below area pressed) for API level 15(and a Samsung S2 device).  The 2cm error happens on all zoom levels too.